# How to know if a model instance was modified by another user

Tags: python, django

I am writing a Django application where users manipulate a Model. A typical session for users is this :

1. they `get` the model ;
2. they do some actions (vizualise the model's datas, change these datas..);
3. then, they `save` the model if they modified something.

But, if two users are manipulating the same instance of the model, and one save his modification after the second loaded it, I want to be able to "notify" the second that the model has changed, so he can reload it.

I could perform a `get` to check if there was a modification in the database every time a view is called, but it doesn't seems optimal.
I have looked at Django's signals too, but I don't know how to send a signal to users manipulating a specific instance of the model.

Do you have any ideas on how I can do it ?

Comment: Maybe you could use a socket server to emit a message that model has been edited or modified when save button is clicked so it will be like stackoverflow, when an answer is added or question is edited a message will come up to tell users on this page that something changed, and here you have the same proccess in your state..

Comment: use VCS `git` ?

Comment: @sahasrara62 I think the title was not clear enough, but I want to know that an **instance** of a model was changed, not the code itself.

Comment: [tis may help](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/283177/how-to-get-real-time-notifications-when-a-database-change-insert-update-dele)

Comment: @MostafaHarb That is a good idea, but in SO, questions are linked to their authors, so it is easy to know who to notify. But what if I want to notify every user that performed a `get` to the question ?

Comment: @Fifi then you'll have to maintain a collection of which users are concerned. You could either use a related model with FKs to user and your model + a timestamp, or something like redis (if you're already using it and don't care about persisting this historic in your db).

Comment: @Fifi nope, in so i could be adding a comment for first time, and while typing a get that question have been edited , so me an every body on this page will get this message an none of us couls have added answer or event comment yet..

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Your solution works fine, I created a model extending the User model with a boolean as you suggested. Do you mind writing an answer so I can accept it ? Or I can write my own if you prefer

Comment: @Fifi I didn't suggest _extending_ the User, but "maintaining a collection of which users are concerned" - ie a model with FKs on both your "content" model and User and a "last fetched" timestamp, plus a "last_modified" timestamp in your model. A single boolean field in your User model won't work (it doesn't tell you which instance__s__ of the "content" model are concerned nor whether they have been modified since the user last fetched them).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers That is right, my model contains also the FK for "content" model.  But I don't understand why I should need timestamps ?

Comment: @Fifi I can only comment on what I undesrtand of what you say about how you implemented the solution - source code would be better if we want to be sure we're understanding each other. And I already explained why the timestamps...